# Actionscript error #1009

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have some nested movieclips in my banner and can't realize how to prevent error it gives me while running. There is a movieclip that runs 3 times and there is a nested movieclip that runs 3 times too, so the nested movieclip runs 9 times totally. When the nested movieclip runs 4th time, it gives me error, but everything works as it's needed - the main thing made in actionscript in the banner is changing text fields.
I attach a source file, please have a look it this. I just don't know what to do! Everything seems to be ok, there is just a few actionscript lines.
The file is located here: [source file](http://rapidshare.com/files/268358766/983x328.rar.html)

It would be also ok just to prevent the error message appearing while running in browser. Actually I don't even need to solve the problem right way, I just need to hide that annoying window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't see what could be the problem, but if you make an empty try/catch statement your errors will not be triggered on the flash player debug version.

```
try{
    functionThatStartWhateverYouChanged();
} catch(e:Error){
    //When you're really debugging an application, you can use here to drop a log message in the console
}
```

And just to remember, the standard version of flash player won't show this errors you're seeing when you're running the debug flash player.